# Can i remap a Danish Macbook Pro keyboard to US?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I found a macbook for sale that has a Danish keyboard.  There are a few special character keys and some are missing.  Can I remap those keys to other characters?  I would like to use it with US english.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of links that might help:

http://lifehacker.com/5882684/the-best-keyboard-remapper-for-mac-os-x
http://lifehacker.com/5720087/how-to-remap-any-keyboard-shortcut-in-mac-os-x

They work for more than just Danish-English. The first one should be more helpful in your case. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have your keys act like a US keyboard by just going to system preferences/language & text/input sources and unchecking the box for Danish and checking the box for US.

Answer (score 0):

As Tom Gewecke mentioned, you can just change the input source in System Preferences. I have used the U.S. layout with a Finnish and UK keyboard with no problems.

Many special characters are at different positions though, so you'll have to memorize them instead of looking at the labels.

European (ISO) keyboards have one more key than U.S. (ANSI) keyboards, and the backtick key is in a different position. You can use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) to change the section key to backtick and remap the backtick key:

```
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::UK_SECTION, KeyCode::BACKQUOTE</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BACKQUOTE, KeyCode::FORWARD_DELETE</autogen>
```